# How to install and run Red Alert 2 and Yuri's Revenge on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, command-and-conquer-red-alert-2, command-and-conquer-yuris-revenge

I have the original CDs for RA2 & Yuri's Revenge (expansion) but the setup programs do not work (neither `autorun.exe` nor `install.exe`). (I've tried both the Allied and the Soviet disks.)

Googling it gives lots of newsgroup postings but either there is no clear explanation or other people claim the instructions do not work.

How can I install and run this great game on Windows 10?

Comment: The Origin version does work on Windows 10, but this is a last resort as it would involve 1. Spending money & 2. Using Origin.

Comment: I couldn't even get the Origin free giveaway of Red Alert 2 to work. On the very first moment of the very first level Tanya would die instantly, no matter how many times I started a new game. Possibly EA have fixed it on Origin now, but I really wouldn't fancy the chances of getting the original executables to work on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

If you can find the .exe files then there is something you can do to get them working. I have the complete red alert collection on Origin and i couldn't play them as well. I found [this article](http://xwis.net/forums/index.php/topic/182360-cc-red-alert-2-windows-8-windows-10-fix/) that shows you how to set up the compatibility settings for the .exe files that should get them running again. I haven't tried to play mine in the last few months what with work getting in the way but the fix should still work okay.

EDIT:: If you can't get the applications to install then try [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/228689/how-to-make-old-programs-work-on-windows-10/) instead.

EDIT (Thanks Frank)::
The first article linked uses the compatibility options that Windows has built in. 
Right click on the program, select properties and there should be a "Compatibility" option where you can tell windows which operating system to point at.

The second article is similiar but instead of using the compatibility option in the properties window of a program instead type "Run Programs made for older" and you should see the option for the compatibility wizard appear. Using it is very simple.
First Click the "Advanced Settings" option at the bottom and then click on 'Run as Administrator' from there the wizard will scan your computer and produce a list of all of the programs installed. If you then select the option for 'Not Listed' at the top and you can then navigate to the install.exe or autorun.exe of your program on the CD and it will attempt to find the best compatibility options to make it run.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that article but I think that is appropriate *after* the installation. I could not even get the game installed.

Comment: really? that is very strange. I'll have a look at mine when I get home and see if i can't find something out.

Comment: @Wikis I just installed Red Alert 2 and Yuri's Revenge on my laptop, its a custom machine with Windows 10 Home and its downloaded and installed no problem. You might have an update for Origin thats preventing you from downloading them

Comment: You may be right! I installed Origin to install the Uprising expansion pack to RA3. On the other hand, I'm not trying to download but install directly from the original CDs.

Comment: When you put the CD in does it show that you have a CD in the drive? If it does then right click on the CD icon, select properties and then go to the compatibility option in the settings and change it to windows XP or 2000 or what ever you think would be best for your use.

Comment: Yes, it does recognise the CD and I can select Properties but there is no Compatibility option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66493/discussion-between-mac-man-and-wikis).

Comment: Please summarize the relevant information from the pages you have linked to.  That way, if ever those pages go down, your answer is still useful to future readers.

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar problems installing old games from their original discs to Win7 and got around the problem by setting up a virtual machine using VMWare. You would need an old o/s like WinXP but its very easy to setup and run and old games work great.